# How to prove this by mathematical induction?

Tags: induction

ok! so i don't have a clue as to how to prove it.

$$\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^n i=((n-m)(n+m+1))/2$$ so the base case is equal to zero because $$\sum\limits_{i=1+1}^1 i=0$$ is this correct? I don't know how to go for inductive step.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you inducting on $m$ or $n$?

Comment: It is to be done by double induction, I think. So do I have to keep n constant for base case as well? I tried keeping n fixed for inductive step, but I couldn't prove it. I took S(1,1) as base case.

Comment: @NatashaJ An appropriately applied single induction is more than sufficient to prove this relation. You can find more details in an answer below.

Comment: Looking quickly it seems that induction on $n-m$ does the trick, no?

Comment: thanks for replying! I will try what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing in mind that your claim - when written out explicitly as a formal predicate - should look as follows:
$$R \colon \equiv (\forall m, n)\left(m,n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge m \leqslant n \Rightarrow \sum_{k=m+1}^n k=\frac{(n-m)(n-m+1)}{2}\right),$$
by far the easiest approach is to consider the predicate:
$$P(m) \colon \equiv (\forall n)
\left(n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge m \leqslant n \Rightarrow \sum_{k=m+1}^n k=\frac{(n-m)(n-m+1)}{2}\right)$$
and realise that $R \Leftrightarrow (\forall m)(m \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow P(m))$. Therefore, in order to establish (prove) $R$ it will suffice to fix *arbitrary* $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and to establish the predicate $P(m)$.

In order to supply a proof for $P(m)$, the most natural choice is to perform induction on the well-ordered set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \geqslant m\}$, since this is precisely the domain over which the universal quantifier comprised in $P(m)$ acts.

More explicitly, you would have to perform just one induction where the base case is $n=m$ and the inductive step consists of assuming the summation relation valid for a certain (arbitrary) $n \geqslant m$ in order to deduce it for $n+1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is informative! But I did not understand why to induct on well ordered set?

Comment: @NatashaJ I am glad you found the answer helpful. What I meant by that remark is that the classical method of *proof by induction* - typically presented and encountered in (standard) exercises as only applying to $\mathbb{N}$ - is actually one instance of a far more general theorem of set theory, according to which - loosely speaking - one can perform induction on *artinian ordered sets* (which are ordered sets with the particular feature that they do not allow the existence of *strictly* decreasing sequences of their elements). Well-ordered sets are in particular artinian *(to be cont.)*

Comment: *(cont.)* artinian, to be more specific they are the *totally* ordered artinian sets and $\mathbb{N}$ together with any of its subsets is in particular well-ordered (under the standard order, of course). In other words, I wanted to hint at the fact that "proof by induction" can be performed in far more general contexts and one should not have ones' thought process limited solely to the "base case $n=0$ and property for $n$ implies property for $n+1$" pattern.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very nice!

Comment: @Natasha J Thank you for taking it into consideration and - once again - I'm glad you found it instructive.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you induct on $m$. Fix $n = N$, and then the base case $m=0$ is the familiar arithmetic progression
$$\sum_{i=1}^N i = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}.$$
Suppose the result is true for $k = 0, \dots, m$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=m+1}^N i = \sum_{i=m}^N i - m = \frac{(N-(m-1))(N+m)}{2} - m = \frac{N^2+N-m^2-m}{2} = \frac{(N-m)(N+m+1)}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have various options.  If I was doing this, I would use double induction as follows : outer induction on $n$ and inner induction on $m$.

First, I would **manually** show that it holds for $n = 2$, when $m$ is any value in $\{0,1\}.$

Then, I would assume that the conjecture holds for all $n=N$ when $m$ is any value in $\{0,1,\cdots, N-1\}.$

Then, I would show that because it holds for $n = (N)$, it also holds for $n=(N+1)$, when $m$ is any value in $\{0,1,\cdots, N-1, N\}.$

I would do this by holding the value of $n$ as fixed at $(N+1)$, showing that it holds for $m=0$, and then showing that if it holds for any $M$ in $\{0,1,2,\cdots, N-1\}$ with $n = (N+1)$, then it must also hold for $m = (M+1).$